# how to count on one column from a table group by another column in another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on two tables called users and department

**users**

| id | id_dep | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 5 | 1 |

**department**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | math |
| 2 | physic |
| 3 | chemistry |
| 4 | economy |
| 5 | history |

What I need exactly is to retrieve all information from department Table with the number of users elements that are from the department table ( group by ) and role = 0.

**Expected results:**

| name | numberOfUsers |
| --- | --- |
| math | 2 |
| physic | 1 |
| chemistry | 1 |
| economy | 0 |
| history | 0 |

I have tried to execute the query but it did not give me any result:

```
SELECT
  count(users.id) as numberOfUsers,
  department.name as name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN department ON users.id_dep = department.id
WHERE users.role = 0
GROUP BY name;
```

What can I modify to get the needed result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are left-joining the wrong way round

```
SELECT
  COUNT(u.id) as numberOfUsers,
  d.name as name
FROM department AS d
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id_dep = d.id AND u.role = 0
GROUP BY d.name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/TwQyei88)